# Copy all matching items from one list to another

Tags: c#

Consider the following code

```
List<string> one = new List<string>();
List<string> two = new List<string>();
```

List one contains 3 strings

```
Test 1
Test 1
Test 2
```

How would I match the string `Test 1` and put each matching string in `List two` and remove the matching strings from list one so it's left with only `Test 2` string

This is what I have so far

```
if (one.Any(str => str.Contains("Test 1")))
{
   //What to do here 
}
```

If I use `AddRange()` it adds the entire list one to list two

Comment: What do you mean by this: *How would I match the string Test 1 and put each matching string in List two*;  What exactly you mean by *match the string Test 1*

Comment: Are you looking for `Intersect` http://www.dotnetperls.com/intersect

Comment: I suggest you try to look into the `foreach` loop and have it loop each item in list 1. if it finds something in list 1,place it in list 2 and remove it form list 1. that could be done by using `indexOf` and `removeAt`. I think you can figure out how to use them by your self.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I want to check if list one contains a certian string and if it does then place that particular string to list two and remove it from list one

Comment: @Izzy: isn't that a completely different requirement? So you want to check if `one` contains "Test 1", if it does remove all "Test 1" from `one` and add a single "Test 1" to `two`, is that correct?

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry if it came across wrong but I want to add each "Test 1" string to List 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you  want to remove all "Test1" from `one` and add them to `two`. So actually you wants to transfer them from one list to another?

```
string toFind = "Test 1";
var foundStrings = one.Where(s => s == toFind);
if(foundStrings.Any())
{
    two.AddRange(foundStrings);
    one.RemoveAll(s => s == toFind);
}
```

Here's a non-LINQ version that is more efficient but perhaps not as readable:

```
// backwards loop because you're going to remove items via index
for (int i = one.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    string s1 = one[i];
    if (s1 == toFind)
    {
        two.Add(toFind);
        one.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The task could also be solved with Linq as follows.

```
var NewOne = one.Where(iString => iString == "Test1")
var NewTwo = one.Except(NewOne);

one = NewOne.ToList();
two = NewTwo.ToList();
```

Comment: One very important side effect of `Except` is that it not only removes "Test1", but also any duplicates. That's because `Except` is a *set operation*. So if the original collection was composed of `[Test1, Test2, Test2]`, the result would be `[Test2]`

Comment: He wants to remove all "Test1" from `one` and add them to `two`. So actually he wants to transfer them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check against this string:

```
string match = "Test1";
```

then use this:

```
 two.AddRange(one.Where(x => x == match));
```

to place all matching records from list `one` into list `two`.

Then, use this:

```
    one.RemoveAll(x => x == match);
```

to remove all matching records from list `one`.

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
two.AddRange(one.FindAll(x => x.Contains("Test 1")));
one.RemoveAll(x => two.Contains(x));
```

The following code

```
List<string> one = new List<string>();
List<string> two = new List<string>();

one.Add("Test 1");
one.Add("Test 1");
one.Add("Test 2");

two.AddRange(one.FindAll(x => x.Contains("Test 1")));
one.RemoveAll(x => two.Contains(x));

Console.WriteLine("ONE:");
foreach (string s in one)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
Console.WriteLine("TWO:");
foreach (string s in two)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

should result in

```
ONE:
Test 2
TWO:
Test 1
Test 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example of a non-LINQ solution, seems like this works well enough:

```
List<string> one = new List<string>(new[] {"Test 1", "Test 1", "Test 2"});
List<string> two = new List<string>();
var toRemove = new List<string>();

foreach (var value in one)
{
    if(value.Equals("Test 1"))
    {
        toRemove.Add(value);
        two.Add(value);
    }
}

foreach (var value in toRemove)
{
    one.Remove(value);
}
```

Comment: I'm fully aware this isn't the "slickest" answer, but still...is it not valid?

Comment: I have to go with @roryap on this one. Other than naming convention, it's still a solution to getting the result that the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        List<string> two = (from i in one
                            where i.Contains("Test 1")
                            select i).ToList();

        one = one.Except(two).ToList();
```

Or more concise :

```
List<string> two = one.Where(i => i.Contains("Test 1")).ToList();
one = one.Except(two).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
//set string to match
string match = "Test 1";
//check each item in the list
for(int i =0; i<one.Count;i++) 
   {
   if (one[i].Equals(match)) //see if it matches
      {
      int index = one.IndexOf(match);//get index of the matching item
      one.RemoveAt(index);//remove the item
      two.Add(match);//add the item to the other list
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
two = one.FindAll(x => x.Contains("Test 1");
one.RemoveAll(x => x.Contains("Test 1");
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of how this code would solve the problem better than the existing answers. Generally, answers with explanations score higher than those without.

Answer (score 0):

[`Sequences`](https://github.com/dcastro/Sequences) has a method for this specific use case, [`Sequence<T>.Partition`](http://diogocastro.com/Sequences/).

```
var lists = one.AsSequence().Partition(x => x == "Test1");

var withTestOne = lists.Item1;
var withoutTestOne = lists.Item2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a groupby clause. Below, I've provided a demonstration. I've included both a method to retrieve a specific item (eg. Test 1) as well as a method to move all existing duplicate items. (See the code comments for further detail.)

```
class Program
{
    static List<string> _firstList;
    static List<string> _secondList;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Initialize test values
        Setup();

        // Display whats presenting in list 1.
        Display();

        // Fill list 2 with all items in list 1 where the item is a value and remove the item
        // from list 1.
        FillListTwoWithSpecificValue("Test 1");

        /* Uncomment the line below if you want to populate list 2 with all duplicate items
                     while removing them from list 1.*/
        // FillListWithAllDuplicates();

        // Display the results after changes to list 1 and list 2 have been applied.
        Display();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Bonus method.  Fills list 2 with any instance of a duplicate item pre-existing in list 1 while removing the item from the list.
    static void FillListTwoWithAllDuplicates()
    {
        // Group the items in the first list
        var duplicates = _firstList
            .GroupBy(item => item)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(grp => grp);

        // Iterate through each duplicate in the group of duplicate items and add them to the second list and remove it from the first.
        foreach (var duplicate in duplicates)
        {
            _secondList.Add(duplicate);

            // Remove all instances of the duplicate value from the first list.
            _firstList.RemoveAll(item => item == duplicate);
        }
    }

    // Fill list 2 with any instance of a value provided as a parameter (eg. Test 1) and remove the same value from list 1.
    static void FillListTwoWithSpecificValue(string value)
    {
        // Group the items in the first list, and select a group according to the value provided.
        var duplicates = _firstList
            .GroupBy(item => item)
            .SelectMany(grp => grp.Where(item => item == value));

        // Iterate through each duplicate in the group of duplicate items and add them to the second list and remove it from the first.
        foreach (string duplicate in duplicates)
        {
            _secondList.Add(duplicate);

            // Remove all instances of the duplicate value from the first list.
            _firstList.RemoveAll(item => item == duplicate);
        }
    }

    // Simply a method to initialize the lists with dummy data.  This is only meant to keep the code organized.
    static void Setup()
    {
        // Initialize lists
        _firstList = new List<string>()
        {
            "Test 1",
            "Test 1",
            "Test 2",
            "Test 3",
            "Test 3",
            "Test 4",
            "Test 4",
            "Test 5",
            "Test 6",
        };

        _secondList = new List<string>();
    }

    // Simply a method to display the output to the console for the purpose of demonstration.  This is only meant to keep the code organized.
    static void Display()
    {
        // Checking to see if the second list has been populated. If not, lets just display what's in list 1
        // since no changes have been made.
        if (_secondList.Count == 0)
        {
            // Display the list 1 values for comparison.
            Console.WriteLine("Items contained in list 1 before items moved to list 2:\n------------------------------------");
            foreach (var item in _firstList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nItems now in list 1 after duplicates being removed:\n------------------------------------");
            foreach (var item in _firstList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nItems now in list 2:\n------------------------------------");
            foreach (var item in _secondList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

The results would be the following:

```
Items contained in list 1 before items moved to list 2:
------------------------------------
Test 1
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
Test 3
Test 4
Test 4
Test 5
Test 6

Items now in list 1 after duplicates being removed:
------------------------------------
Test 2
Test 3
Test 3
Test 4
Test 4
Test 5
Test 6

Items now in list 2:
------------------------------------
Test 1
Test 1
```